# Does creating a Express server in Google Cloud functions or AWS lambda extend the function lifetime forever (till timeout)?

Tags: aws-lambda, google-cloud-functions

I see multiple usecases of hosting a web server inside Cloud Functions. GCP by itself provides HTTP triggers and functions framework.

And cloud functions are supposed to ephemeral, meaning they must die as soon as the process they are handling is complete.

But if host a express server inside a cloud function technical the process inside cloud function will never because the server keeps listening. so will i be billed the whole time till the cloud function die due to timeout?

Or is there something google does intelligently to kill the function once any request received by cloud function is resolved?

Comment: Have you checked this [thread1](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71933286/18265570) and [thread2](https://stackoverflow.com/q/59561961/18265570)?

Comment: thread1 helped. thanks

Answer (score 1):

> But if host a express server inside a cloud function technical the process inside cloud function will never because the server keeps listening.

No that is not how those services work at all. They do not keep listening for requests.

> Or is there something google does intelligently to kill the function once any request received by cloud function is resolved?

That is correct. The entire express server is started up, sent the request, and once the response is received the server is stopped/destroyed. For each request that comes in.

Cloud Functions and AWS Lambda will try to be efficient by keeping the server (the container) around and reuse it if there are more active requests coming in, but as soon as it has been idle for a bit they will kill it.

Comment: thanks for the info. Is there any reference document where there are explained in detail?

Comment: The functions are processes and internally these processes are creating a web server inside it. If the web server is running, the process should never terminate. And so the function should not shutdown was my train of thought.